# Drawing text inside D3 rect element?

Tags: text, d3.js, rect

I have code here and I need to add text into the rect element on the right of all the hexagons and have it act like a paragraph inside of a div with a given height and width and have it wrap properly. Here is the jsfiddle. and the code that draws the rect is below:
http://jsfiddle.net/2nykc/

```
var infoRect = svgContainer.append("rect");
    var infoRectAttr = infoRect.attr("x", function(){
        return infoDivX;
    })
    .attr("y", function(){
        return infoDivY;
    })
    .attr("width", function(){
        return infoDivWidth;
    })
    .attr("height", function(){
        return infoDivHeight;
    })
    .style("fill", "rgb(30,180,134)")
    .style("stroke", "black")
    .style("stroke-width", 3)
    .attr("id", "infoRect");
```

Comment: Sounds like you need [`foreignObject`](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1424037).

Comment: could you provide assitance using the jfiddle i provided? i am not familiar with foreignObject and its semantics

Comment: here's an updated jsfiddle with what you posted... It's still not working http://jsfiddle.net/n4Cbz/

Comment: You have a typo in there -- it should be `svgContainer` instead of `svg`.